# Generating infinite random training data in an input_fn in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is it possible to create an `input_fn` that generates random data infinitely to use with the Estimator API in Tensorflow?

This is basically what I would like:

```
def create_input_fn(function_to_generate_one_sample_with_label):
    def _input_fn():
        ### some code ###
        return feature_cols, labels
```

I would then like to use the function with an `Estimator` instance like this:

```
def data_generator():
    features = ... generate a (random) feature vector ...
    lablel = ... create suitable label ...
    return features, labels

input_fn = create_input_fn(data_generator)
estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=ANY_NUMBER_OF_STEPS)
```

The point is to be able to train for as many steps as needed, generating the required training data on the fly. This is for model tuning purposes, to be able to experiment with different training data of varying complexity so that I can get an idea of the capability of the model to fit the training data.

---

**Edit**
As jkm suggested, I tried using an actual generator, like this:

```
def create_input_fn(function, batch_size=100):  
    def create_generator():
        while True:
            features = ... generate <batch_size> feature vectors ...
            lablel = ... create <batch_size> labels ...
            yield features, label
    g = create_generator()
    def _input_fn():
        return next(g)
    return _input_fn
```

I had to add a batch size to get it to run. It now runs, but `input_fn` is only called once, so it does not generate any new data. It just trains on the first `<batch_size>` samples that were generated. Is there some way to tell the estimator to refresh the data using the provided `input_fn`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get the desired behavior using recent Tf Dataset API, you need tensorflow>=1.2.0

```
# Define number of samples and input shape for each iteration
# you can set minval or maxval as per you data distribution and label distributon requirements
 num_samples = [20000,]
 input_shape = [32, 32, 3]
dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.random_normal([num_examples+input_shape]),  tf.random_uniform([num_samples], minval=0, maxval=5)))
# Define batch_size
batch_size = 128
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
# Define iterator
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
# Get one batch
next_example, next_label = iterator.get_next()
# calculate loss from the estimator fucntion you are using
estimator_loss = some_estimator(next_example, next_label)
# Set number of Epochs here
num_epochs = 100
for _ in range(num_epochs):
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    while True:
        try:
            _loss = sess.run(estimator_loss)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break
```

Comment: I think it might make sense to reinitialize the iterator every `num_samples` steps with `sess.run(iterator.initializer)` to get new random values.

Answer (score 0):

Word of warning - I did **not** work with Tensorflow myself, I'm just going off the docs for the API.

That said - if there's no gotcha in there, you should be able to do what you need. Just make the generator a, well, **generator** (yield features and labels rather than return them) and putting the whole generation in an endless loop. So for example:

```
def data_generator():
    while True:
        #do generatey things here
        yield feature, labels
```

This function will be able to be called repeatedly, each time generating new values once per call.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It helped, but it still isn't doing what I wanted. See the edited question :)